# Python basic Calculator program doesn't return answer

Tags: python, calculator

So I am trying to figure out how to make a calculator with the things that I have learned in python, but I just can't make it give me an answer.

This is the code I have so far:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract (x, y):
    return x - y


def divide (x, y):
    return x / y


def multiply (x, y):
    return x / y


print("What calculation would you like to make?")
print("Add")
print("Subtract")
print("Divide")
print("Multiply")


choice = input("Enter choice (add/subtract/divide/multiply)\n")


num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))        

if choice == ("add, Add"):
    print(add(num1,num2))

elif choice == ("subtract, Subtract"):
    print(subtract(num1,num2))

elif choice == ("divide, Divide"):
    print(divide(num1,num2))

elif choice == ("multiply, Multiply"):
    print(multiply(num1,num2))`
```

Comment: To help catch bugs like this, try adding an 'else' block at the end of your if/elif blocks - then you could see that it wasn't matching any of your choices if you reached the 'else'

Comment: I did have an else at the end but i removed it because it kept going for it, so that means that the code above it wasn't selected and thus something went wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's what it meant. Removing the else just meant you couldn't see it skipping the other choices, it doesn't change whether they match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of:

```
choice == ("add, Add")
```

You want:

```
choice in ["add", "Add"]
```

Or more likely:

```
choice.lower() == "add"
```

Why? You're trying to check that the choice input is equal to the tuple ("add, Add") in your code which is not what you want. You instead want to check that the choice input is in the list ["add", "Add"]. Alternatively the better way to handle this input would be to lowercase the input and compare it to the string you want.

Comment: aah so the way i made it you had to type add, Add instead of either one!? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I have a very basic calc. you can try so that you can learn from it. while True:

```
firstNum = int(input('first number'))
op = input('enter operation')
secondNum = int(input('second number'))

if op == '-':
    print(firstNum - secondNum)
elif op == '+':
    print(firstNum + secondNum)
elif op == '*':
    print(firstNum * secondNum)
elif op == '/':
    print(firstNum / secondNum)
else:
    print('ERROR, You must enter an operation.')
```